# Why is setInterval being called automatically in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a simple clock that starts and stops on the press of a button. Here I have set a variable equal to a setInterval so that I can clear it later on. But for some reason, it is being called without the button being pressed.

Here the autoInc should have been called ideally when I pressed the "Start" button but it gets called anyway.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, Button } from "react-native";

export default class Counter extends Component {
  increaser = () => {
    this.setState(prePre => {
      return { counter: prePre.counter + 1 };
    });
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      wantToShow: true
    };
    autoInc = setInterval(this.increaser, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.wantToShow)
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 50, textAlign: "center" }}>
            {this.state.counter}
          </Text>
          <Button title="Start" onPress={this.autoInc} />
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because your constructor calls `setInterval`

Comment: @tkausl does my constructor call all the setIntervals, even those are not in the constructor scope?

Answer (score 3):

A full `react` example here, you just have to translate functions in react native.

Create a variable `this.interval=null` in your constructor, assign to this the interval in the `startFn` , then just remove it with `window.clearInterval(this.interval);`

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.interval = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  startFn = () => {
    console.log("assign and start the interval");
    this.interval = setInterval(this.callbackFn, 1000);
  };

  stopFn = () => {
    console.log("clear interval");
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
  };

  callbackFn = () => {
    console.log("interval callback function");
  };

  render(props, { results = [] }) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <button onClick={this.startFn}>start Interval</button>
        <button onClick={this.stopFn}>stop Interval</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j737qj23r5

Comment: Once again, the timer starts without me explicitly pressing the button.

Comment: Just updated the answer, is because your variable assign.

Comment: this works, but if a add another button to clearInterval,i.e., clearInterval(autoInc) the interval does not get cleared

Comment: AppNovice I updated the example, now you can clear the interval. If you have other questions pls let me know.

Comment: so any idea why the setInterval got called without my explicit calling?

Comment: Yes, you assign it directly to a variable inside the constructor, when you use `setInterval(fn, 1000)` this will start the interval. In your example `autoInc = setInterval(fn, 1000)` your variable is the interval itself, so the interval is started. In my exmample I assign to the variable the `setInterval` only when I press the button and I want to start the interval. 
Bassically `variable = setInterval(fn, 1000)` is an explicit call for the `setInterval`. variable is the output of your `setInterval` function, the actual interval.

Comment: As a comparison, if you have this `let variable = Math.random()` , this will call the `Math.random` function. In your case you call the `setInterval()` function.

Comment: @AppNovice You ARE calling it explicitly, in your constructor: `autoInc = setInterval(fn, 1000)`. You're calling it and assigning the return value to `autoInc`

Comment: And if is Working please consider to mark the answer as `good`, other users will know that this answer is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you **call** `setInterval(this.increaser,1000)` and then assign its return value to the **global property** `autoInc`.
`this.autoInc` is `undefined` in your render function.

It looks like

```
autoInc = setInterval(this.increaser,1000)
```

is simply incorrectly written and what you want instead is:

```
this.autoInc = () => setInterval(this.increaser,1000)
```